# Hibernate Search : fetch indexed field containing the given key word

Tags: hibernate, indexing, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm new at using Hibernate Search, and here is my implementation:
I start with the entity and its field

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "ngram",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class ),
filters = {

  @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class),
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class,
    params = {
      @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "3"),
      @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "3") } )
}
)

@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Field
    @Column(nullable=false,length=30,name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable=false,length=30,name="last_name")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(length=128)
    @Field(analyzer=@Analyzer(definition="ngram"))
    private String login;

    @Column(length=255)
    private String password;
```

In my database i have 2 records with the following data :

---

|id        | first_name    | last_name    | login        | password   |

---

|1         | NULL          | NULL         | mednabli     | ***        |
|2         | NULL          | NULL         | med-nabli    | ***        |

when I apply a research on the field login I display the login of results I get:

typed keyword : med

result        : mednabli med-nabli

typed keyword : med-

result        : (nothing) while I need to get med-nabli

typed keyword : nabli

result        : med-nabli while I need to get mednabli med-nabli

typed keyword : kamed

result        : (nothing) while I need to get mednabli med-nabli

So please is there a way to make the search get to desired result, is there an analyzer I should rely on it to make my application works As I want to ??

Answer (score 1):

So, first thing is that you can't get what you want with only one field. So you need to create another field (see @Fields annotation to define several fields on a single property). This new field should have a keyword tokenizer and a lowercase filter. You should then build your query by querying both fields (with a should) with the query on the second one being a wildcard query "*yoursearch*".

This will solve all your cases, except this one: "typed keyword : kamed". As for this one, can you provide how you build and execute your query?

NB: It's not a good idea to define a Stop filter on your login search so you should remove it.

Comment: For the key word kamed, this last will be split into 3-grams: kam, ame, med and so i will have to get all logins containing "med". I ll try your solution Ty for reply :)